# Can you display an image with just CSS?

Tags: css

I'm making externally hosted CSS files for use by other people. I want to be able to create a small logo in the bottom left corner that links back to my page. Is this possible using just CSS? I cannot use HTML for the image/link because people can and will remove my credit.

Comment: *create a small logo*: yes. *links back to my page*: no

Comment: They can override your CSS, too, or download it and rip out your logo. The answer here is not a technical one, but a legal one.

Comment: Just a heads up... that won't help. Sorry. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1081494). You are better off just putting it in your terms of use (note that IANAL). Imagine you embed it using CSS. Now the page owner can just have other css with `!important` that matches images, and then makes your image hidden. Instead, make it against the TOS to do that.

Comment: @ceejayoz If they knew how to download the file, edit it, reupload it and import it from the new url they wouldn't need me. It's much easier to delete a single HTML tag than do all that, a small hurdle can be very effective with people who don't know what they're doing.